# Different ways to Initilialize struct with a referenced member

Tags: c++, struct, instantiation

Supose we have this 2 structs:

```
struct simple_struct
{
    unsigned int n1;
    unsigned int n2;
};

struct ref_struct
{
    struct simple_struct& st1;
    unsigned int n2;
};
```

How many ways are to instantiate a **ref_struct** in c++? (without implementing a constructor for this struct)

im trying to instantiate ref_struct because i think its interesting to know different ways to do it...

Comment: Don't be sorry for being curious.

Answer (score 3):

<del>None. (AFAIK, I might be wrong)</del>

You could do it like

```
ref_struct x = {{1,1},1};
```

if the member was `const`, i.e.

```
struct ref_struct
{
    const simple_struct& st1;
    unsigned int n2;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pre-existing simple_struct instance to initialize ref_struct without a constructor.

```
simple_struct simple = {1,2};
ref_struct ref = {simple, 3};
```